# failure to load repository information

Tags: updates, repository, 19.10

I am running 19.10 on a Lenovo flex 11 and all seems to be working smoothly. I regularly check for updates and often get something new installed apparently. Well, today I checked for updates and get the message "Failed to load repository information". My network connection is good...hello, my question is getting in here...so what is going on? Fetching e-mail works, surfing the web works, streaming works, but am unable to download repository information. What's up?
results of update attempt:

```
tom@tom-Lenovo-FLEX-6-11IGM:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for tom: 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                    
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease            
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release [933 B]
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
tom@tom-Lenovo-FLEX-6-11IGM:~$
```

my ignorance is nearly complete, but it appears to me that something may be lacking in the place where updates live - I am grateful for the assistance I get here.

Comment: Please edit your question above to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: The linked question is about using PPAs this question is about using a third party repo (Google) which was presumably added via a deb file. I don't see how that is a duplicate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that the signature for google earth is not verified ( and it seems that its a common problem with google earth) so try the following:
Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Time to update now :

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: this is the remedy and worked fine - problem solved

Comment: would you mark the question as 'solved'

Comment: I would mark the problem as solved

Comment: No literally Tom Koehler, you should have the option to mark it as solved with a check mark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer it helps others too :)